# Why is Django creating a "static" directory at run time?

Tags: python, django, bower, django-pipeline

I'm new to Django.
I'm using Django-Pipeline with Bower. [I followed this documentation](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storages.html#using-pipeline-with-bower)

Here's the structure of my Django project:

```
|- myProject
    |- manage.py
    |- bower.json
    |- bower_components
        |- jquery
        |- bootstrap
        |- ...
    |- myProject
        |- settings.py
        |- static // This is the folder that gets created
            |- jquery
            |- bootstrap
            |- ...
    |- myApp
```

Is it a normal behaviour for Django to create a "static" directory inside myProject? If I manually delete the static folder, it automatically gets created at the next page refresh.

What I don't get is I have specified where to find static files using the STATICFILES_DIRS setting. So to me it would seem logical that Django (in development environment at least) would serve files directly from my bower components folder.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I am not running collectstatic. This folder gets created just when I refresh the page.

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS sets where to pick files from. STATIC_ROOT sets where to put them in. I never had the case but, as it's a target directory, it feels logical it would get created if it does not exist.

Comment: In my development machine it does not automatically create a static folder, only when I manually run `manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. It seems logical it would get created to me as well. But I'm not running collectstatic so this is why I find it strange...

Comment: Collectstatic come in picture when you set BEBUG=False      , main task of collectstatic is copy all static file to static root directory

Answer (score 1):

django-pipeline by default collect static to save results of compiling.
See option [PIPELINE_COLLECTOR_ENABLED](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=collector#pipeline-collector-enabled) to turn it off (appeared into django-pipeline version 1.6.5). But it may cause an errors, if you are using something like LESS.

Comment: This is the answer. Should be marked.

Answer (score 0):

How are your PIPELINE settings? 
In particular the `output_filename` settings of PIPELINE_JS and PIPELINE_CSS?

Because I think django-pipeline is responsible for the creation of such folder, while compiling and minifying sources, not django

Comment: The output_filename looks like this: 'output_filename': 'css/styles.css'. However I'm not running collectstatic, so I don't think these should matter... ?